# Grunt: change order of js files in index.html

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am building angular project with grunt and let's assume that i have follow structure:

```
-- app.js
-- modal
----createTemplate
------createTemplate.js
----modal.js
```

and createTemplate.js implements controller for module, declared in modal.js, for example:

**modal.js**

```
angular.module('modal', [])
    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope) {
        //some stuff
    });
```

**createTemplate.js**

```
angular.module('modal')
    .controller('CreateTemplateCtrl', function($scope) {
        //some stuff
    });
```

and i have Grunt task, that builds index.html:

```
index: {
  build: {
    dir: '<%= build_dir %>',
    src: [
      '<%= build_dir %>/src/**/*.js'          
    ]
  }
}
```

So, when i build index.html, i get follow order of files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/app/home/modal/createTemplate/createTemplate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/app/home/modal/modal.js"></script>
```

What leads to error **Module 'modal' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**, because declaration of module is happened after call to it.

So, how should i edit gruntfile to add files not in alphabetcal order, but in order of breadth-first-search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to use separate files for module definition, and call it like 'modal-module.js'. After that you can easily inject module-files first, with this parameters:

```
index: {
  build: {
    dir: '<%= build_dir %>',
    src: [
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/app.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*module.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*constants.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*provider.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*enum.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*model.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*config.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*filter.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*directive.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*decorator.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*interceptor.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*service.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*workflow.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*repository.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*resolver.js',
        '<%= build_dir %>/app/**/*controller.js'        
    ]
  }
}
```